# Displaying absolute values for bar graph (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to create a graph similar to the one hypothetical one below where:
1-absolute values for the entire group are shown on top of each bar, and the
2- % breakdown per group is shown as a proportion for each bar and period.

First, here is a data example:

## Print data example with specific columns

Here is my attempt in creating the graph:

```
df <- 
df %>% 
 group_by(directed_to_whom, treatment_details) %>%   
  mutate(direct_period_count=n()) %>% #count of directed to whom by month
  group_by(treatment_details) %>% 
  mutate(period_count=n())  %>% ###total count per month
  mutate(directed_to_whom_percentage = direct_period_count/period_count*100) #percentage
```

The code works without errors but it is not displaying the % or proportion per subgroup and I am unable to show the absolute value by period:

```
ggplot(experimentgraph_directed_to_whom, aes(x = treatment_details, y = period_count, 
                       fill = directed_to_whom, label=directed_to_whom_percentage))+
      geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1) + 
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 4)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold")) +
  theme_bw()+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 5, face = "bold"),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Here is how I ideally want the bar graphs to be displayed:
[image]

Following the proposed solution below, I wrote:

```
df <- 
  experimentgraph_directed_to_whom %>%
  distinct()
```

then for the plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = treatment_details, y = period_count, 
                                             fill = directed_to_whom, label=directed_to_whom_percentage))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = 1,label = sum(direct_period_count)), vjust = 0) +  
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::label_percent(0.1, scale = 1) (directed_to_whom_percentage)), position = position_fill(.5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1) + 
                       geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 4)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold")) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 5, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Do an SO search on “[r] stacked bar text”. Multiple duplicates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to label geom\_bar(position = 'fill') using geom\_text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165372/how-to-label-geom-barposition-fill-using-geom-text)

Comment: Thanks, it gets me closer to the graph but not fully. See the updated post. @MAurélio

Comment: @nesta1992 to provide the sample data you can do this `dput(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example you have repeated lines to create the plot:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#> # Groups:   treatment_details [1]
#>   directed_to_whom  treatment_details direct_period_count period_count directe…¹
#>   <chr>             <chr>                           <int>        <int>     <dbl>
#> 1 Private employers pre                                 3            5        60
#> 2 Private employers pre                                 3            5        60
#> 3 MoL               pre                                 2            5        40
#> 4 MoL               pre                                 2            5        40
#> 5 Private employers pre                                 3            5        60
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​directed_to_whom_percentage
```

We just need unique rows

```r
df <- 
  df %>%
  distinct()
df
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#> # Groups:   treatment_details [1]
#>   directed_to_whom  treatment_details direct_period_count period_count directe…¹
#>   <chr>             <chr>                           <int>        <int>     <dbl>
#> 1 Private employers pre                                 3            5        60
#> 2 MoL               pre                                 2            5        40
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​directed_to_whom_percentage
```

Then we use  `geom_text(..., position = position_fill(.5))` to print the numbers in the middle.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = treatment_details, y = period_count, 
                                             fill = directed_to_whom, label=directed_to_whom_percentage))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = 1,label = sum(direct_period_count)), vjust = 0) +  
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::label_percent(0.1, scale = 1) (directed_to_whom_percentage)), position = position_fill(.5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1) + 
                       geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 4)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold")) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 5, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @MAurélio
but unfortunately the solution isn't working well with the data. See the edited post.

Comment: For the data you provided, it works. Please consider giving an example that represents your real problem